# Como hacer transacción de bases de datos con Sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize

espero puedan ayudarme.
En estos momentos tengo una aplicación con el funcionamiento de back, realizada con Node.js, Sequelize, postgres y Fastify.
Pero estoy teniendo un problema que no se como resolver, pasa de que mientras lleno mi base de datos con los nombres de los registros, se va haciendo cada vez mas grande y mas grande, me da miedo que al pasar 1 año o menos la aplicación se vuelva lente o en su defecto no funcione por la cantidad de registros que esta teniendo, entonces lo que quiero hacer es que al pasar cada mes, el programa haga una transacción de los datos a una carpeta, donde haga un archivo por mes de los datos generados y deje las tablas nuevamente vacias, sin embargo quisiera que al momento de necesitar esos datos, yo pueda acceder a esos archivos y buscar información si llegara a necesitarla.
La verdad espero puedan ayudarme, agradezco mucho a toda la comunidad